# Property of non-object notice after submitting CiviCRM Webform with Contributions

Tags: webform-civicrm, contributions, contribution-page

I’m using Webforms for CiviCRM 4.28 for a membership registration and payment form and have Pay Later set as the payment method. When the form is submitted I get the following errors shown on the confirmation screen once the form has been submitted.

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'tax_amount' of non-object in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::checkTaxAmount() (line 4272 of /xxxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php).
Notice: Trying to get property 'total_amount' of non-object in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::checkTaxAmount() (line 4278 of /xxxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php).
Notice: Trying to get property 'total_amount' of non-object in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::checkTaxAmount() (line 4279 of /xxxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php).
Notice: Trying to get property 'fee_amount' of non-object in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::checkTaxAmount() (line 4278 of /xxxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php).
Notice: Trying to get property 'fee_amount' of non-object in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::checkTaxAmount() (line 4279 of /xxxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php).
```

I have the Membership and Contribution tabs of the CiviCRM Webform panel set up as follows.
[image: Webform Membership Panel][image: Webform Contribution Panel]
The payment screen looks fine and the message shows after the form has been submitted.
[image: Payment Screen]
[image: Confirmation Screen (Showing Error)]
I’m running CiviCRM 5.16.2 against Drupal 7.67.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of quick thoughts:

1. upgrade to Webform CiviCRM 5.x (we’re no longer supporting 4.x)

Edit: we have now officially disabled support for D7 - 4.x - you will now have a ‘unsupported version’ warning in your Drupal status report.

2. what is your PHP version?
3. always switch off notices on production sites: goto admin/config/developement/logging and set to -> None
4. open an issue on our drupal.org webform_civicrm project page and give us exact steps to reproduce

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. Regarding point 1 - do you mean this version: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/releases/7.x-5.x-dev? Also I'm running PHP 7.2.21.

Comment: Still listed as 5.x-dev? Looking into that.

Comment: Yes it is. Great thanks. Look forward to hearing back.

Comment: Touched base with Coleman - we're keeping the 5.x.-dev until the remaining PRs in the queue (mostly API rewrites of direct DB queries) have been reviewed/tested. It's definitively what you want to be on from now on and going fwd.